# Semantic UI Dropdown Option Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui, custom-data-attribute, html-dataset

I've been trying to attach a `data-*` attribute in a Semantic UI dropdown `option` but to no success *(the data attributes are not being copied to the resulting dropdown options)*.

Here's the structure of my `select`:

#### HTML

```
<select id='my-dropdown' name='department'>
    <option value='1' data-wsg='something'>Department 1</option>
    <option value='2' data-wsg='another'>Department 2</option>
    . . .
    <option value='n' data-wsg='custom data'>Department N</option>
</select>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#my-dropdown").dropdown({
    allowAdditions: false,
    fullTextSearch: true,
    onHide: function() {
        // Some codes.
    },
    onChange: function(value, text, choice) {
        // Access the data-wsg attribute of the selected option.
    }
});
```

I've been reading around a bit but all I saw regarding data attribute support was storing the settings in there. Not really what I need.

Hopefully someone has done something similar and let me know what the solution is.

Answer (score 3):

Its not pretty, but you can use the details in the onChange to hunt down the data attribute. The functionality you are after was specifically rejected here - https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/931

```
onChange: function(value, text, choice) {
    $(this).children('option[value=' + $(choice).data('value') + ']').data('wsg')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work pretty consistently by attaching a data attribute to the main dropdown object, then just going two more levels to get the selection I want, like this

`'[data-testid="region-dropdown"] > div.visible.menu.transition > div:nth-child(4)'`

Semantic UI wraps all the dropdown options in a div with the `visible.menu.transition` class and then each option is it's own div, so the `nth-child` lets you select a specific option as long as the order of your options is consistent.

I've found this works with pretty much any input type, it's just a matter of figuring out where to set the data attribute, then finding the path to the selector past that.

For example, a specific tab can be selected with something like

`'[data-testid="tabs-menu"] > div.ui.attached.tabular.menu > a:nth-child(1)'`