# Semantic-Ui-React Dropdown Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm using React-semantic-ui dropdown. I can't seem to find how to add a data-attribute to the dropdown options. I'd like to add data-key attribute to the drop-down options and then use those keys later.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009621/semantic-ui-dropdown-option-data-attribute) resource here but this doesn't help.

```
<div className="dropdownMenu">
    <Dropdown
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countries}
        placeholder="Select Country"
        onChange={updateCountry}
        defaultValue={selectedCountry}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: You may share some live sample of your project (e.g. at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) ) to better understand your use case

Comment: what you mean by data-attribute? can you explain?

Comment: @Shivaraj I believe OP means like a `data-something` in the dataset of each of the option tags.  To put it on the dropdown itself, you could just include `foo={"bar"}` and get it back with `data-foo`, but how do you pass something through to each of the options?  OP, if that's correct, please include it in your question!